# pdf file is not showing in UIWebView when downloading from url in iOS 8.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using iOS 8.3 and when showing pdf file from url in `UIWebView` it is showing white screen. When I am using local file then it was showing correctly. Can anyone help me ?

```
 NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kmmc.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];
_webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
_webView.delegate=self;
[_webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Comment: What is your question? As `"I am unable to understand what's going wrong ?"` isn't a question it is a statement. Also `scalesPageToFit` should be done when the page has finished loading as at the time that method is called it doesn't know what the size is.

Comment: Ok. Can you check it and if you know what was the problem. Please tell me.

Comment: try fileURLWithPath method for creating url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems perfect. Please make sure that the IB connections are proper. Then implement the delegate methods

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  NSLog(@"Start Loading...");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  NSLog(@"Finished Loading");
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
  NSLog(@"Error Occured:%@", error);
}
```

It'll take some time to download, and keep eye on the delegate methods, see what are you getting on console

Comment: I got the solution the problem was that pdf file has 64 mb. So that's the reason to take loading. So up to that completion of loading it showing like white screen.Thank you.